# Does a matrix $\rho$ satisfies $\rho^2 = I$ if you are given that $\rho^3 = \rho$

Tags: matrices

Looking at the [spin matrices](http://easyspin.org/documentation/spinoperators.html) of $S=1$:

[image]

Obviously $S_y^3 = S_y$ because it must satisfies $S_y$'s characteristic polynomial $x^3-x = 0$.

Hence, I would expect the $S_y^2 = I$ which is not true:

```
>> rho=[0 -i/sqrt(2) 0; i/sqrt(2) 0 -i/sqrt(2); 0 i/sqrt(2) 0]

rho =

   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.7071i   0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.7071i   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.7071i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 0.7071i   0.0000 + 0.0000i>> rho*rho

ans =

   0.500000000000000                   0  -0.500000000000000
                   0   1.000000000000000                   0
  -0.500000000000000                   0   0.500000000000000
```

Comment: Take $\rho = 0$.

Comment: If $S_y$ were invertible then $S_y^3 = S_y$ would imply $S_y^2 = I$.  Is $S_y$ invertible?

Comment: Reformulating in a slightly different way what @Mark has said, you cannot simplify a matrix equality by a non invertible element (which is the case for either of the three Pauli matrices). The reason behind that : "simplification" is equivalent to "multiplying LHS and RHS by the inverse of the matrix you want to simplify"... and this inverse doesn't exist...

Comment: "Are all the zero det matrices isomorphic?" Of course not, in any reasonable sense of the word isomorphic, one would not call the zero matrix and the matrix [[1,0][0,0]] isomorphic. If this is your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\rho^3 = \rho$ and if $\rho$ is **invertible**, we can "divide by $\rho$" on both sides to deduce that $\rho^2 = I$. However, this is not necessarily the case.  For instance, take the diagonal matrix
$$
\rho = \pmatrix{1\\&-1\\&&0}
$$

Comment: So what would be a proper proof that $S_y^3 = S_y$?

Comment: Compute $S_y^3$.  Is it the same as $S_y$?  Then you're done.  If you want something a bit more *subtle*, it suffices to note (from the construction of spin operator) that $S_y$ Is *similar* to the $\rho$ that I present in my answer (or if you prefer, similar to $S_z$).

Comment: How can I show it from the characteristic polynomial? Is there a name for such matrices? $M^n$ = $M$ and $M$ isn't invertible?

Comment: @0x90 if you compute the characteristic polynomial (which turns out to be $x^3 - x$), then it suffices to apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Comment: If $M^2 = M$, then $M$ is called a projection.  I don't know of any name for the more general case that you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are over the complex numbers the matrix is similar to a matrix in jordan form.

And it is easy to see that the only matrices in Jordan form that work are the diagonalizable ones which only have eigenvalues $0$ and $\pm 1$.

So essentially the matrices that work are those of the form:

$$B\begin{pmatrix}a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & a_2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & a_3\\ 
\end{pmatrix} B^{-1}$$

Where $B$ is an invertible matrix and $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are all $0,1$ or $-1$.